Show field in Grafana graph tooltip but not use in graph or to distinguish series
I am using Clickhouse and Grafana.
SELECT ts, price FROM trades correctly graphs price. Now I'd like to add the side enum (BID, ASK). This will create two fields price BID and price ASK. When I hover over a point to show the tooltip, I can see the side. Is there a way to show the side in the tooltip, without having two fields?
It is not a big deal for side, but when I include order_id (integer), so I can see which order_id is associated with a trade, 1) it graphs the order_ids, which I don't want at all (I can kind of fix this by hiding it in the Viz, but that's not ideal), and 2) since it's an integer it doesn't associate the price with the order_id, it treats them as separate series. I've tried associated them by converting to text (SELECT order_id::text), but then we get the problem that the order_id is used to distinguish series.
My ultimate goal is to have information in the tooltip that isn't used to distinguish fields or graph, so I can click on a point and get an ID I can do further queries specifically for (instead of copying the time which is not specific enough). Thanks!
